# Output formatting in C++

Tags: c++, format, output

Hi i am printing some output data to a txt file , which will be used by another program , but to make the data pleasant to eyes need to align them in columns.
Could someone help me please-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>     // std::cout, std::fixed, std::scientific

int main () {


          int r=1;
          double value1=-1.187;
          double value2=5.273430;
          double value3=5.27343056896;
          double value4=0.0000056868;
          int i=1;
          int r1=10;
           int r2=2;
          double value5=1.1875985;
          double value6=-5.273430;
          double value7=-0.27343056896;
          double value8=1.0000056868;


        std::cout.precision(6);
        std::cout << std::fixed;
       // std::cout << std::setw( 8 );
        //std::cout << std::setfill ('0');
        std::string space="   ";

        std::cout<<r<<space<<value1<<space<<value2<<space<<value3<<space<<value4<<space<<i<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<r2<<space<<value5<<space<<value1<<space<<value4<<space<<value3<<space<<i<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<r1<<space<<value5<<space<<value6<<space<<value7<<space<<value8<<space<<i<<std::endl;


  return 0;
}


The result looks like this

1   -1.187000   5.273430   5.273431   0.000006   1

2   1.187599   -1.187000   0.000006   5.273431   1

10   1.187599   -5.273430   -0.273431   1.000006   1


but i really want is

1   -1.187000   5.273430   5.273431   0.000006   1

2    1.187599  -1.187000   0.000006   5.273431   1

10   1.187599  -5.273430  -0.273431   1.000006   1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQTXk.png)

Comment: Use [setw(COLUMN_WIDTH)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to align data

Comment: Setw() is the best option for what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 easy way to solve your question.

Why don't try to use old good `printf();`? It's really better in for output formatting data.

```
printf("%1.5lf\t%1.5lf\t%1.5lf\t%1.5lf\t%1d\t\n",r, value1, value2, value3,value4, i);
```

You already included `<iomanip>`, then why don't you try to use `setw`?

```
std::cout<<std::setw(10);
std::cout<<r<<value1<<value2<<value3<<value4<<i<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
std::string space="   ";
```

to

```
std::string space="\t";
```

Comment: Please provide some additional information how this improves formatting.